# Encodeer and decoder in python/ from wav to bin

Tags: python, audio, encoder, decoder

How can I:

- read my audio file
- stores  in a binary file,

Can somebody give me examples to implement encoder and decoder in python?

Comment: What do you mean with "binary file"? How does such a file look like?

Comment: file with ***.bin

Answer (score 2):

You can use scipy.wave to read and write the wav file. To store the data, you could use numpy.

If the audio file is effectively encoded with 16 bits per sample, you don't have to do anything and this should will something like:

```
 from scipy.io.wavfile import read as wavread
 from scipy.io.wavfile import write as wavwrite
 import numpy as np

 sr, sig = wavread(audioFileName) #read the audio file (samplig rate, signal)
 sig_int8 = np.uint8(sig) # cast the data in uint8
 np.savez(out_file, sig = sig_int8) # store the data

 npzfile = np.load(out_file + '.npz') #load the data
 sig = npzfile['sig']

 wavwrite(audioFileName2, sr, sig) #write data in wav file
```

Comment: If i need quantize the audio samples from the sound file to 8 bit per sample, what i should change in your program?

Comment: In scipy write, there is a rate option. See here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.write.html

Comment: i wrote smt like : wavwrite(file name, sr,'uint8') anf got the error: 'str' object has no attribute 'dtype'.

Comment: I edited the answer